# trying to get photos using graph api of Facebook

Tags: xcode, facebook-graph-api, ios5

I am trying to get data of my Facebook photos using:

```
[self.facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/photos" andDelegate:self]
```

but the result I am getting is empty data.
I am getting friends list with this:

```
[self.facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/friends" andDelegate:self]
```

Has anybody encountered this?

Comment: is there any thing i am missing in authorization part? why i am not getting data for photos but feed and friends?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call `me/permissions` to see what permissions the access token has prior to making your call to the photos.  Ensure it has user_photos turned on before making that call.

Comment: this what it shows.{
            "create_note" = 1;
            email = 1;
            installed = 1;
            "photo_upload" = 1;
            "publish_stream" = 1;
            "share_item" = 1;
            "status_update" = 1;
            "video_upload" = 1;
        }